# add icon on css menu

Tags: css, menu, icons

im trying to insert an icon on my menu, im using the next menu:
[menu css3](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/913/Multi-Level-Drop-Down-Menu-Navigation-with-CSS3)

it is a multi level drop down menu. i will like to insert icons at any level

```
<div id="navmenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Three Levels</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Level 1</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 1 op2</a></li>
        </ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

i want to add icons to my menu from css, what you think will be the best way to do it?

if you can show me a simple code example i will appreciate it

tks

Comment: Unless you want a background image, the best way to add icons is with an `<img src="" width="" height"" alt""` tag. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want a background image or sprite, the best way to add icons is with an `<img src="" width="" height"" alt"">` tag.

You should insert the images inbetween the `<a></a>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a class to the `li` element:

```
<li class="background">
    <a href="#">Level 2</a>
</li>
```

**CSS:**

```
.background { 
   background: url('yourImage.png') no-repeat;
}
```

**Or applying it directly to the `li` tag:**

Comment: really no need to wrap in span, why not add a class to the li

Comment: @Blowsie - yeah sure, either would be fine. I usually don't attach backgrounds to li items directly but it is perfectly valid.

Comment: prevents divitis, improves semantics and reduces the dom size, thus improving performance, really no reason to add the span.

Comment: This method is not responsive.